# After sending shutdown command, ssh session doesn't terminate

Tags: debian, ssh, systemd, shutdown

Whenever I send the command to turn off or restart my Debian servers, my shell is left hanging and unresponsive (can't type any commands).

[image]

Performing the same action in Ubuntu results in the session gracefully closing so I don't have a tied-up terminal left hanging there. **Is there a package I need to install or a configuration change to be made so that I can get this same behaviour on Debian?**

Comment: Does the same behavior occur with `sudo shutdown -h now` (for poweroff), and/or `sudo reboot` (for restart)?

Comment: yes, it occurs with those as well.

Comment: NB you can kill one of these hung ssh sessions by typing <enter>, tilde, and period (~.).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
apt-get install libpam-systemd dbus
```

Also make sure that you have `UsePAM yes` in your ssh config.

```
grep -i UsePAM /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Unfortunately, you need to reboot for the solution to take effect...

Detailed explanations on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/706494/63361).

Comment: I just had the same problem on ubuntu 16.04 for which the previous solution didn't work but this one did.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like that's a `systemd` issue currently tracked under [bug #751636](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=751636).

When the host is shut down or restarted, `systemd` might shut down the network before it kills the ssh session.

There are a couple of solutions provided but nothing concrete:

1. Using `acpid/acpi-support-base` to handle the power events & add the following to the `/etc/acpi/powerbtn-acpi-support.sh`

   ```
   else
   -       # Normal handling.
   -       /sbin/shutdown -h -P now "Power button pressed"
   +
   +       if [ -x /bin/systemctl ] ; then
   +           echo "\nPower button pressed\nThe system is going down for system halt NOW!" |\
   +            /usr/bin/wall -n
   +           /bin/systemctl --force poweroff
   +       else
   +           # Normal handling.
   +           /sbin/shutdown -h -P now "Power button pressed"
   +       fi
   +
   fi
   ```

   and then make aliases in your `~/.bashrc`:

   ```
   alias reboot='echo "The system is going down for system reboot NOW!" |\
   /usr/bin/wall -n ; /bin/systemctl --force reboot'

   alias poweroff='echo "The system is going down for system halt NOW!" |\
   /usr/bin/wall -n ; /bin/systemctl --force poweroff'
   ```
2. Creating `/etc/systemd/system/ssh-user-sessions.service` with the following in it:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Shutdown all ssh sessions before network
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   TimeoutStartSec=0
   Type=oneshot
   RemainAfterExit=yes
   ExecStart=/bin/true
   ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall sshd
   ```

Comment: it's good to know its a bug thats known about. I tried the second solution, but it doesn't appear to work for me when sending the reboot command. I made sure to make it executable.

Comment: Reload the systemd daemon: `systemctl daemon-reload`, also in-order to activate the systemd service immediately:  `systemctl start ssh-user-sessions.service` and to enable the service at bootup `systemctl enable ssh-user-sessions.service`

Comment: Running the first 2 commnds did the trick. Running the third command resulted in: `The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.` but doesn't seem to be needed.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that Unit file may include an `"[Install]"` section, which carries installation information for the unit. This section is not interpreted by `systemd` during runtime. It is used exclusively by the **enable** and **disable** commands of the `systemctl` tool during installation of a unit.

Comment: I added `[Install]` followed by `WantedBy=multi-user.target` to the file, which resulted in `systemctl enable ssh-user-sessions.service` not throwing an error and results in the service taking effect across reboots. Is there anything wrong with doing this?