# terminate ssh session on host reboot

Tags: linux, bash, sshd

assume I have a ssh session to a remote host like `ssh user@host tail` for example and now somehing causes that host to reboot. How can I configure the session to  terminate immediately and return back to shell? (To attempt reconnection in a while loop w/o user input)
Thanks

Comment: Is that not the default behaviour?

Comment: @Tomasz no, it takes quite a while until it finally disconnects and terminates the session.... :( - if the session has no active I/O anyways and just sits there...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After sending shutdown command, ssh session doesn't terminate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216950/after-sending-shutdown-command-ssh-session-doesnt-terminate)

Comment: Ok, but which Linux then?

Comment: Set `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` to suitable values in your `~/.ssh/config` file or by using `-o` options on the `ssh` command line.  See `man ssh_config` for details.

Comment: @Tomasz which Linux? Which version? I'm currently running on kernel `4.15.0` on this machine

Comment: @ottomeister I've experimented with those without much success... The solution I think is here (I still have to try it out!): https://serverfault.com/questions/706475/ssh-sessions-hang-on-shutdown-reboot/706494#706494

Answer (score 1):

@cerr `autossh` can help you do that. It has a feature to start a copy of ssh and monitor it, then restarting it in case of stop passing traffic, server destination reboot. See more [here](https://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/).

also you should be used `tmux` or `screen` to create and keep the tty session on server destination, and combine them with `autossh`. In `autossh` documentation, they recommend that we should work together with `screen` for perpetual session.

Comment: Tien - Thanks,m i've uysed `autossh` before - for different purposes though but I'm well familiar wirth it, I also know and use both, `screen` and `tmux` - wouldn't want to live without them! ;)